# Derivatives with Related Rates

Tags: calculus

The radius of a circle is increasing at a constant rate of $7 cm/min$. When the area of the circle is 16$\pi$ $cm^2$, what is the rate of change of the area? Round your answer to three decimal places.

This is what I have so far:

- $A=\pi r^2$ $\to$ dA/dr= 2$\pi$r.

  So, 16$\pi$ $cm^2$ = $\pi r^2$ -> r=4
- $dr/dt$= 7 cm/min [Given]
- Find $dA/dt$.

I know $dA/dt = (dA/dr)\cdot(dr/dt)$.

So, I have $dA/dt$ = (2$\pi$r)$\cdot (7 cm/min $), that is $ dA/dt = 175.929$

I will appreciate any assistance with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the area of the circle is $16\pi\, cm^2$ then the radius is $r$ is equal to $4\, cm$.
Hence, according to your work, 
$$\frac{dA}{dt}=2\pi r\cdot \frac{dr}{dt}=?\; cm^2/min$$
What is the correct result?

Comment: Would it be 2π(4) ⋅ 7 =  56π = 175.929? Thank you very much for your help @Robert Z !!

Comment: @Lola Yes, and don't forget the units $cm^2/min$.

Comment: @Lola BTW, if you are new here, please take a few second for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: thanks for the link! It was a nice mini tour and covered the important details. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

We have $r(t)=7t$, hence $A(t)= 49 \pi t^2$, thus $A'(t)=98 \pi t$.

Let $t_0$ so that $A(t_0)=16 \pi$. This gives $t_0=4/7$. Hence $A'(t_0)=A'(4/7)=56$.